# access lookup and yes/no proper techniques?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm building a database in access and need to include the ability to migrate over to SQL Server at some point if need be. Because of this, certain access techniques need to be avoided (right?)

Two of those are boolean and lookup tables. My understanding is that yes/no check boxes do not migrate correctly to SQL Server, and so VBA is a better option to parse a 0/1 truth value rather than the -1/0 that is traditionally used. Again, please correct me if I'm wrong!

The other thing is to avoid using the lookup wizard in the table design to restrict entry. My understanding is that the artificial (or perhaps "hidden" is a better word) relationships to tables that don't actually exist in the database causes problems when migrating and running queries on those fields.

So my question is, how should I manage lookup values? I was thinking of just leaving the table design as a regular field and then in the vba form creating a combo box that references another **real** table in my database. Is this the proper technique? Is there anything I'm not grasping fully? Is there anything I should know otherwise?

Comment: Note that while 0/1 is a good idea, you will have to be very careful with checkboxes - look at absolute value. Avoid anything other than standard design, so no lookups in tables. Separate tables with combos are fine. Make sure you create appropriate views and ensure you use parameters.

Comment: As an aside, names for indexes etc do not translate well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted the true/false column values don’t matter since when you move the data to SQL server and continue to use Access, then the values are translated.

However, as a “habit” you can use the keyword true/false.

```
Select * from tblCustomer where InvoicePaid = False
```

The above means you don’t care or have to remember to use -1 or 0.

So the fact that SQL uses different values for true/false really does not matter since the above query will continue to operate just fine after you migrate the data to SQL server.

And you should avoid the use of lookup columns at the table design level. As a general rule one should not allow editing of data in the table view, so once again this issue really much becomes a non issue.

For a typical form, a combo box will in most cases store the first column “PK ID” of the table that drives the combo box, and will also “display”/search by the next column. So simply use the wizard to drop + create a combo box on a form, and the results + functioning of that combo box will be the SAME as using a lookup column, but you have correctly normalized tables behind the scenes. And this data setup will move up to SQL server and continue to work “as is”.

So “looking up” of data really does not change much here, the only issue is one should not be editing data by directly opening the tables. Even after you migrate data to SQL server, your tables are now linked, but once again since no one is editing those tables directly, then the lookup column feature will not be missed in anyway.

So combo boxes on forms etc. don’t need some lookup column, but are simply driven by a SQL statement that the wizard creates when dropping such boxes on a form.

Comment: ah ok, so the form lookup wizard is fine, since it will write it to the table and the relationship isn't stored, the data is. Am I understanding this correctly? Basically, the way a form does a lookup is irrelevant to the table design, so long as the data is committed and now left as just an address or pointer

Comment: Also, quick question - if I set up a lookup field in the table, build the form (with the lookup already there since it does that automatically) and then delete the lookup in the table, the form still has the information but the table is now just a regular text box. Does this work or is something happening in the background that I should just build the lookups myself?

Comment: If the combo box is NOT multi-value, then it should continue to work as if you built that combo using the control wizard. The combo box (no matter how you built it) will usually “return” the PK id from the given row the user selects and this value is then stuffed into a “plain jane” regular long number” column in the current form. So yes combo boxes function the SAME when created by the wizard, or by dropping a lookup column into a form, or by creating the combo box without any wizard. Nothing special is occurring and we simply are selecting “row” and PK ID from the combo box in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break out your question into the two separate parts.  1) Differences between boolean/bit fields in MS Access and SQL Server.  2)  MS Access lookup fields

1)  Special care needs to be used for boolean/bit fields between MS Access and SQL Server since they store the values differently.

> SQL Server:  1=True | 0=False
>
> MS Access: -1=True | 0=False

Generally speaking this is not a big issue as the ODBC/OLEDB drivers handle this issue, but you might run into a query where you want to test a bit field.  In that case you should generally use:

> '0' for False
>
> '<>0' for True

2) MS Access lookup fields are not supported in SQL Server, and generally speaking they should be avoided in MS Access as well.  The idea here is that you separate the data (tables) from the presentation (forms), which is best practice .  Build MS Access forms that manipulate all of the data in the tables, and do not use lookup fields.